# How to ignore spelling in a run in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm using the built-in SpellCheck for the WPF RichTextBox and would like to ignore spelling errors for some text runs (validated paths).  What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dictionary isn't extensible at the moment, I achieved this behavior by setting the language to "none".